# Combining two installs of mysql

Tags: mysql

Noobish questions

The StartupParameters.plist points to MySQL 5.5.27-community. When I run Querious, a database management application, and create a db, it adds the db to an older version - MySQL 5.5.18 (specifically to usr/local/mysql-5.5.18-osx10.5-x86_64/data).

Questions: how do I move the dbs in the older version of MySQL to the current one? If I do, and then delete the old MySQL directory, will I be ok or are there other changes which need to be made?

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply dump the old databases using mysqldump or similar.  Then import those dumps into the new server.  You should then be able to safely uninstall your old server and remove the directories.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of exporting the databases and then importing them to another. In your case, use [mysqldump](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html)  to export the database from the older server and use [mysql import](http://linuxmoz.com/mysql-import-database/) to import into the newer one.

It is okay to safely uninstall the older version once the database has been exported.

```
usr/local/mysql-5.5.18-osx10.5-x86_64/> mysqldump -u username -p database > exported.sql

(location of the newer db)>mysql -u username -p -h localhost database < exported.sql
```